# How to chart the count of items?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a spreadsheet that is filled by a form. It contains values like the following:

```
Timestamp           Person  Category
2012-02-13 10.31.22 a       x
2012-02-13 11.06.37 b       y
2012-02-13 11.34.32 c       x
2012-02-14 09.22.35 d       z
2012-02-14 09.24.01 e       w
2012-02-14 11.06.20 f       x
2012-02-14 22.39.33 g       y
```

I would like to make a bar chart that shows a bar for each category, with the value the number of rows per category.

Should I calculate new columns in a new table before creating the chart, or could it be done in one step, and how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is an excellent time to use a pivot table.

Select columns **B** and **C**, then click on **Data** → **Pivot table...**

In the **Pivot table editor** sidebar on the right side:

- In the **Columns** section, add the **Category** field. Uncheck **Show totals** if you do not want the **Grand Total** column.
- In the **Values** section, add the **Category** field and summarize by **COUNTA**.

Now select the pivot table data on the sheet and click on **Insert** → **Chart**. Select **Column chart** for the Chart type.

New form submissions will update the pivot table and the updated pivot table will update the chart. This is what the pivot table and chart look like using the example data you provided in your question:

[image: Pivot table and chart]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirement, this is indeed possible in a single step:

[image: WA23939 example]

The order for the X-axis may be reversed but if required in alphabetical order some sorting of the source data would be my advice.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the count column in a new sheet that way if you start sorting the rows of data you won't mess up the columns with the data for the chart.

I am assuming that you are using countif to make the data for the bar chart.